# Mern stack Heroku build gives white page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, dom

i deployed my mern stackapp in heroku and it returns empty page and there is no error in heroku logs i checked using command `heroku logs --tail`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const sendMail = require('./mail');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
});

// test route
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello people!!");
})

//mail route
app.post('/api/mail', (req, res) => {
    console.log("mail sent !!", req.body)
    const isSend = sendMail(req.body);
    if (isSend) {
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'sucsess',
            message: 'Mail sent !!'
        })
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({
            status: 'failed',
            message: 'Unable to send Mail !!'
        })
    }
})

app.use(express.static('client/build'));
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    console.log("inside production00");
    const path = require('path');
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        console.log("inside send file", __dirname);
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './Client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    });
}


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(" serving started @", port);
})
```

this is my server file.

[image: this is the ui output]

i'm also getting the html resopnse when served but it gives white screen.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd Client && npm install && npm run build",
    "client": "npm start --prefix Client",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

these are the package json scripts

Comment: If your app use the MERN stack ,how / where are you running react?

Comment: www.newgin-sam.herokuapp.com